# Why most titles on codegolf stack-exchange looks so funny?

Tags: language

Titles of this question [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111477/la-la-land-no-wait-moo-moo-moonlight) & [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103448/pen-pineapple-apple-pen-with-your-own-pens-pineapples-and-apples?rq=1) looks so funny to me.

Why most of titles on codegolf stack-exchange looks so funny ?

Is it **click-bait**?

I really want to ask this for so many days, I think it is right time to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **yes** my friend.

You will notice this everywhere on the internet today and the simple reason behind it is *short attention span*. No one one the internet today, spends more than 5 seconds on a page/screen without scrolling **UNLESS** it is scandalous/out-of-the-box/kinda over the top/outright attention seeking.

Headlines have never needed more work than the 21st century and for the late 90's kids and the Millennial's

Comment: I disagree- click bait means tricking someone to click on something they don't actually want to click on or read, or at least making the content look way more interesting/engaging than it actually is. Hence the word "bait" since fish die when they take the bait...

Answer (score 0):

Not clickbait, in the sense that they are deceptive or over-promising- the titles are designed to accomplish 3 purposes:

- Entice people to participate
- Briefly describe or represent the challenge
- Introduce a theme or add some humor to make it more fun

Comment: I think you just defined **click-bait** :P

Comment: I thought that click bait had a negative connotation. In other words, it tricks you into clicking something but you actually aren't interested in it. If you really want to find a fun puzzle to do, and you click on one, that's not click bait.